# What's the difference between brioche feuilletee and croissant dough?

Tags: baking, dough

There are two similar laminated doughs, but recipes make them slightly different, but overall what are the main differences between brioche feuilletee and croissant dough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are very similar, here is the difference according to *The Bread Bible* by Rose Levy Beranbaum:

> Croissant and brioche have the same ingredients: flour, yeast, salt,
> sugar, milk, and butter. There are only two significant differences:
> croissant dough contains almost double the amount of butter and has
> only milk as the liquid component, whereas the liquid for brioche
> dough comes mostly from eggs, with only a little milk. The eggs in the
> brioche dough give it an airy cake-like crumb, while the large amount
> of butter in the croissant dough, and the way in which it is rolled
> and layered into the dough, gives it its flaky crumb.

Comment: I would add also that the preparation of the brioche dough does not require laminating, they're made of... brioche pastry and not puff pastry. The latter I'd call "croissand dough". The fact that the original question mentions "brioche feuillete" kind of confuses me but I hope I understood it correctly

Comment: @DavidP brioche feuilletee Is a laminated brioche

Comment: are we speaking about the preparation of the dough or final shape of the product? One could shape a brioche dough (i.e. dough done without layering butter and dough) in a croissant shape and a puff pastry (pate feuillete) doesn't have to be shaped as croissant. Would a different shape be called a brioche feuillete?